# How do you do ranges in the x-axis for a bar graph in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, range

I'm creating a bar graph and need to be able to have ranges on the x-axis.

Example Data

```
Redear Sunfish  195

Redear Sunfish  210

Redear Sunfish  212

Redear Sunfish  215

Redear Sunfish  235

Redear Sunfish  242
```

I want to get ranges on these sizes of fish (e.g. 50 - 100 mm, 100 - 150 mm, etc).

My code as of right now is

```r
ggplot(data=Sunfish_Total_Length)+
  geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=Total_Length_mm))
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, one potential solution is with the `cut()` function, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

Sunfish_Total_Length <- tribble(
  ~"Species", ~"Total_Length_mm",
  "Redear Sunfish", 195,
  "Redear Sunfish",  210,
  "Redear Sunfish",  212,
  "Redear Sunfish",  215,
  "Redear Sunfish",  235,
  "Redear Sunfish",  242
  )

Sunfish_Total_Length %>% 
  mutate(`Size Category (mm)` = cut(Total_Length_mm, breaks = seq(0, 250, 50))) %>%
  ggplot(data = ., aes(x = `Size Category (mm)`)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

--

'Non-tidyverse' style code:

```r
# Non-pipe notation (i.e. no "%>%")
library(ggplot2)

Sunfish_Total_Length <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Species = c(
    "Redear Sunfish",
    "Redear Sunfish",
    "Redear Sunfish",
    "Redear Sunfish",
    "Redear Sunfish",
    "Redear Sunfish"
  ),
  Total_Length_mm = c(195, 210, 212, 215, 235, 242)
)
Sunfish_Total_Length
#>          Species Total_Length_mm
#> 1 Redear Sunfish             195
#> 2 Redear Sunfish             210
#> 3 Redear Sunfish             212
#> 4 Redear Sunfish             215
#> 5 Redear Sunfish             235
#> 6 Redear Sunfish             242

Sunfish_Total_Length$`Size Category (mm)` <- cut(Sunfish_Total_Length$Total_Length_mm, breaks = seq(0, 250, 50))
Sunfish_Total_Length
#>          Species Total_Length_mm Size Category (mm)
#> 1 Redear Sunfish             195          (150,200]
#> 2 Redear Sunfish             210          (200,250]
#> 3 Redear Sunfish             212          (200,250]
#> 4 Redear Sunfish             215          (200,250]
#> 5 Redear Sunfish             235          (200,250]
#> 6 Redear Sunfish             242          (200,250]

ggplot(data = Sunfish_Total_Length, aes(x = `Size Category (mm)`)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>